# Github - Baixar projeto (Iniciante)

Tags: git, github

Estou iniciando no Git-Hub... Baixei a versão Git-Hub para Windows (versão com interface gráfica). Consigo criar repositório, fazer commit e publicações.

Queria saber como posso baixar um projeto feito por um outro usuário, realizar modificações e submete-las ? É possível fazer o download do projetos de outros usuários em .ZIP?

Att,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso você queira copiar um repositório Git já existente — por exemplo, um projeto que você queira contribuir — o comando necessário é `git clone`, por exemplo:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/schacon/grit.git
```

Isso cria um diretório chamado `grit`, inicializa um diretório `.git` dentro deste, obtém todos os dados do repositório e verifica a cópia atual da última versão. Se você entrar no novo diretório `grit`, você verá todos os arquivos do projeto nele, pronto para serem editados ou utilizados.

Após realizar suas contribuições, basta fazer o `commit`, o dono do repositório por sua vez, terá que autoriza-lo, caso contrário seus `commit's` não serão adicionados no repositório.

Comment: Github.com/shacon seria o endereço do projeto que eu quero baixar?

Comment: Não, esse endereço se refere ao usuário, github.com/schacon/grit é o projeto propriamente dito, caso queira acessar pelo seu navegador, porém para clona-lo deve-se adicionar a extensão .git. (Obs: isso via comando, porém no endereço do projeto existe um botão visual para clonar o projeto)

Comment: Tentei acessar este projeto que você me passou pelo navegador, mas não aparece a opção de clonar. Aparece Create New File, Upload Filé, Find File  outras opções menos Clone.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/LGGPH

Comment: Consegui. Pelo que entendi temos que clonar um repositório inteiro. Se houve vários projetos dentro de projeto não tem a opção de clonar um diretório específico.

Comment: Exato, não se esqueça de selecionar uma resposta que solucionou seu problema para auxiliar outras pessoas que eventualmente tenham esta dúvida e venha buscar resposta aqui. Abrass