# Como posso conectar com meu repositório novamente?

Tags: git, github

Eu tinha no meu pc uma pasta conectada com meu repositório do github, recentemente eu formatei o pc e perdi essa pasta, queria saber como me conectar com meu repositório e continuar sendo o master branch? sendo o mesmo usuário

Comment: abra um cmd e digite git clone url_do_repo

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Github - Baixar projeto (Iniciante)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191063/github-baixar-projeto-iniciante)

Comment: Mas a pasta deletada não tem haver com o controle de branch do REMOTO, não tem nem sentido, o REMOTO é o REMOTO, o LOCAL é o LOCAL, se perdeu o LOCAL mas salvou tudo antes de perder bastar clonar novamente e seguir de onde parou e pra ter acesso ao master é questão de permissão no REMOTO, se tinha permissão ao seu usuário antes provavelmente tem ainda, não tem haver com a pasta deletada.

Answer (score 1):

- Instale o [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads);
- Abra o Terminal ou Prompt de Comando;
- Navegue até a pasta em que deseja colocar os seus códigos;
- Execute `git clone <<url do seu repositório>>` Exemplo: `git clone https://github.com/vuejs/vue.git`;

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma `nova pasta` em qualquer lugar que você queira e a partir dela fazer o seu `master`, ai você `clonar` seus projetos nesta pasta.
Um conselho é você ter o `GitBash`, ai você abre ele direto na sua nova pasta onde vai ser seu `master` e a partir dai você pode fazer um `clone` apos `conectar` a sua conta do `Github`.

Answer (score 0):

eu tive um problema semelhante recentemente, e a solução foi a seguinte:

- Faça um *git clone* para baixar o repositório na sua máquina;
- Feito isso, dê um *git init*, *git add -A*, *git commit* etc. no projeto, como se fosse um projeto novo, normalmente.
- Depois disso, feito tudo certinho, na hora de fazer o *git push*, você vai passar o atributo **--force**, então ficaria assim:

```
git push --force origin master
```

O *--force* vai apagar tudo o que tem no seu repositório e substituir pelo sistema que você está enviando, por isso, muito cuidado ao utilizá-lo, nesse caso não tem problema porque é o seu próprio repositório.

Ao fazer esse processo, você vai voltar a poder utilizar a branch master normalmente, comigo funcionou, mas no meu caso foi porque eu queria ter o projeto em duas máquinas :)

Espero ter ajudado. Abração!